# MS Access Overflow Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting an Overflow error in Access when this line runs

```
intAT = Nz(DLookup("at_ID", "qryAT", "at_sc_ID=" & Me.sc_ID & " AND at_OT=0"), 0)
```

If I add `Debug.Print Nz(DLookup("at_ID", "qryAT", "at_sc_ID=" & Me.sc_ID & " AND at_OT=0"), 0)` just before that line, it prints the id number just fine, but still errors during the assignment on the next line.

I can also get it to work by adding a criterion to the query that limits all the results to those that occur before a certain day and time. It ONLY works limiting the query to before that particular time, not after an earlier time. If any of the records after that time are included, it overflows again. I have looked at the data that was entered after that time and it all seems fine, but I am not sure what exactly I should be looking for. The `at_ID` associated with the first record that causes it to fail is `32838` if that helps at all.

Comment: convert `intAT` to double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `intAT` was declared as Integer type.  But 32,838 is too large for an Integer.  (Integer can hold numbers from –32,768 to 32,767) So it triggers error #6, *"Overflow"*.

Use a Long Integer instead.

```vb
Dim lngAT As Long
lngAT = Nz(DLookup("at_ID", "qryAT", "at_sc_ID=" & Me.sc_ID & " AND at_OT=0"), 0)
```

Comment: I believe, as per Access 2007, int gets implicitly dimensioned as a long.

Comment: That seems to do it. But, in order to avoid this problem in the future, do you have any idea why it works fine with numbers up to 32837? 32837 is obviously greater that 32767.

Comment: Are you saying the `DLookup` returned `at_ID` values between 32768 and 32837 inclusive, and those were stored in `intAT` without error?  I don't believe that's possible *if* `intAT` was declared as Integer.

Comment: Ah, no. My mistake, it wasn't actually assigning it. Thanks for your help.